# WHERE clause with OR operator not giving intended result

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

I want to write a stored procedure for a search function. I have a database of movies and I should be able to search a movie by `Movie.Name`, `Movie.Producer`, `Movie.Director` and appearing `Cast.Name`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RetrieveSearchResults
    @tokenParam VarChar
AS
    Select *
    from 
        (Movie 
    join 
        Cast on Movie.MovieID = Cast.MovieID) 
    join 
        Actor on Actor.ActorID = Cast.ActorID
    where 
        (Movie.Name like '%' + @tokenParam + '%')
        or (Movie.Producer like '%' + @tokenParam + '%')
        or (Movie.Director like '%' + @tokenParam + '%')
        or (Actor.Name like '%' + @tokenParam + '%')
```

Upon execution

```
RetrieveSearchResults 'Almighty'
```

I get almost all tuples with no similar literal as 'Almighty'

Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try declaring the varchar limit.  VARCHAR(100) or something like that.  It may be making assumptions on the length and cutting it down to a VARCHAR(1) or similar.  The problem with declaring VARCHAR without a length is the system will assign for you and it may not be what you expect.

Comment: This is correct https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length